# Daterangepicker: My 2nd calendar returning NaN

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I have 2 calendar, the date needed and the good thru. I used jquery whenever the date needed changed then I have function named called GetGoodThru.

In my function this is where you get the value of the first calendar which is the date needed then I want to set my 2nd calendar minDate as my first calendar.

**View**

```
<input type="text" name="date_needed" id="date_needed" class="form-control dates" required="required">
<input type="text" class="form-control dates" id="good_thru" name="good_thru" />
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.dates').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    // minDate : new Date(), maxDate: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 10)),
    showDropdowns: true
});
$('.dates').on('change',function(){
        var date_needed = $(this).val();
        $('#good_thru').data("daterangepicker").minDate(date_needed);
        alert(date_needed);
    })
```

**Function**

```
function editGetGoodThru()
{
    var date_needed  = new Date($('#date_needed').val());
    // var terms           = parseInt($('#terms').val(), 10);
    if(!isNaN(date_needed.getTime())){
        date_needed.setDate(date_needed.getDate());
        var good_thru = $('#good_thru').val(date_needed.toInputFormat());
        $('#good_thru').minDate(good_thru);
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Date");  
    }
}
```

Question:How can I set as minDate for my 2nd calendar depends on the 1st calendar?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the whole process but notice: A. In `JQuery` section you missed `$` in the line `('#good_thru').data("daterangepicker").minDate(date_needed); alert(date_needed);` and in the `Function` section you missed `.data("daterangepicker")` in the line `$('#good_thru').minDate(good_thru);`

Comment: Actually, I tried it also but it didnt work.

Comment: Ok. Can you create a working [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) with your code? It will be much easier for me to try to debug and solve it. Please, [notify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/303669) me when you ready.

Comment: How can I include the daterangepicker.css?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the plugin you're using but if it does, you can use the cdn links: http://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage. If not, please post a link to the plugin website.